# Wordpress Plugin with Database connection

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress Version 2.9.2 for my blog.when i am trying to include a database connection in one of my plug-in which is not working properly.Which did not get the database connection.But in all other directory it is possible to use a common connection.So,now I am using manual coding in all of my plug-in file.Any ways to getting a common connection in all of my plug-in.Help me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should study more about wordpress

eg:

```
<?php
$table = "wp_table";
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 1=1", ARRAY_A);
?>
```

this a common connection

Comment: Thank you.I am a beginner with word press